# How to read beginning of a file after reaching its end?

Tags: c++, file, windows-10, codeblocks

**let my file contain:** (file name:PROFILE.txt)

```
1 2 3 4 5`
```

**I use the below code to read and get the data**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
fstream profile;
int n;
int main()
    {
        profile.open("PROFILE.txt",ios::app|ios::in|ios::out); // file name is PROFILE.txt
        long start = profile.tellg(); //marks the point of beginning of the file
        a:
        profile>>n;
        long p = profile.tellg(); //marks the current point of the file cursor
        cout<<n<<" "<<p<<endl;
        if(n==5)profile.seekg(start); // or if(p==-1)profile.seekg(start);
        goto a;
        return 0;
    }
```

**Output was:**

```
1 1
2 3
3 5
4 7
5 -1
5 -1 
5 -1
5 -1
..
...
.... //so on
```

But, **EXPECTED OUTPUT (or the output that I want):**

```
1 1
2 3
3 5
4 7
5 9
1 1
2 3
3 5
4 7
5 9
1 1
2 3
3 5
4 7
5 9
.
..
... //so on
```

**PROBLEM:**
The problem is after it reaches the end of the file! it fails to go to the beginning of the file! and fails to obey seekg();! But suppose if the it didn't reach its end it works fine has it should!

What is my mistake and how to fix it! and what should be the code?

Please Note: I am c++ beginner! so please try to answer me by simple C++ program code and please try to answer me by step by step!

I hope you understand my program and my question!

[PICTURE of my CODE,OUTPUT,FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8J8x.png)

[After Serge Ballesta code fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8qHL.png)

***PLEASE NOTE that the following codes and outputs are from CODE:BLOCKS (latest version) running in Windows 10 (64 bit) PC*** *(others info: i7 Processor, RAM: 16GB,GPU: 4GB)*

[TO SEE MY OTHER Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39629844/how-to-read-beginning-of-a-file-after-reaching-its-end-using-c-rbix)

Comment: Is [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) what you want?

Comment: When I run the same code, the output is 1 1
2 3
3 5
4 7
5 9
1 1
2 3
...

Comment: how did u get 5 9??? not possible! did u save ur file as this "1 2 3 4 5"

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the content of my file.

Comment: [Check thisl](http://i.stack.imgur.com/b8J8x.png) it don't know! maybe its only to me the problem is occurring ! did u use code  blocks? and see my link

Comment: Maybe you should try if(n==5) profile.seekg(0, profile.beg);

Comment: nope! failed to work! same output! i already tried different ways of using seekg();

Comment: I am using linux machine with g++4.9

Comment: well ! i am using win10 ! linux and mac r far better in compiling the program! and executes better! and have less error!

Comment: You are only reading that file, while don't you use `ifstream profile("PROFILE.TXT");` in main instead?

Comment: @Bob__ actually i took it from main program which read and writes a files too! so it is fstream!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed code:**

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    using namespace std;
    fstream profile;
    int n;
int long count_numbers ( int long num) //to count no of digits stored or entered in an int
 {
   int count =0;
   while (num !=0)
    {
      count++;
      num/=10;
    }
   return count;
 }

int main()
        {
            profile.open("PROFILE.txt",ios::app|ios::in|ios::out);
            a:
            long past= profile.tellg(); 
            profile>>n;
            long p= profile.tellg();
           if (p == -1) //thanks to Serge Ballesta
            {
                        profile.clear();
                        profile.seekg(0);
                   p=past+count_numbers(n)+1; // +1 to add space
            }
                cout<<n<<" "<<p<<endl;
            goto a;
            return 0;
        }
```

Program output:

[image: PROGRAM OUTPUT]

Special thanks to Serge Ballesta (for his help and for his segment of his code)

If there is a better and simpler way than this, Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce when testing with `if (n == 5) ...`. I cannot even imagine how you system gives you that result!

Here is what happens on my system:

- read numbers 1 to 4 and position in the file immediately after the digit
- read number 5 and position at position 9 **immediately before the end of file**
- as no error has been detected to far, the `seekg` is executed and the file is rewinded

So I get (like @user3286661 does) 1 1 2 3 3 5 4 7 5 9 1 1 2 3 ... (new lines omitted for brievety). According to the standard, that is the normal output.

But I get (almost) your output if I use `if (p == -1) ...` because now the following occurs

- read number 1 to 5 and position at 9 before the end of file
- next read hits the end of file. Since that moment every access to `profile` will give an error because we are now past the end of file
- `p = profile.tellg()` returns -1
- `profile.seekg(0)` is not executed because of the end of file error
- `profile >> n` does not change the value of `n` which stays at 5

So I get (as mandated by standard): 1 1 2 3 3 5 4 7 5 9 5 -1 5 -1 ... (newlines still omitted)

How to fix: simply **clear** the error condition:

```
if (p == -1) {
    profile.clear();
    profile.seekg(0);
}
```

But this kind of programming calls the following remarks:

- you use a goto where a while loop would be much better. goto should never be used for loops and only for very special use cases because it does not make the structure evident
- you never test the state of the stream after any operation. The is the real cause of you problem. If you had done, it would have been evident that the `profile` stream was still in `eof` mode after the `seekg` and that the bad condition had to been cleared

Comment: Prefect bro, thx worked! I finally fixed and learning! all thx to u buddy!

Comment: but i get 1 1,
2 3,
3 5,
4 7,
5 -1,
1 1,
2 3,
3 5,
4 7,
5 -1, but i want 5 9 to come! ur code fix the problem with seekg but i want 5 9 to come too! how to fix!

Comment: [check this!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8qHL.png) after i used ur code! i get this!

Comment: i then made few changes ! [check this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GEnfR.png)! but how does seekp function  even after it reachs the end of the file after it read the input 5 from the file! i know how did 1 0 can but how did seekp work now?

Comment: [Can help me in this question too!! Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39629844/how-to-read-beginning-of-a-file-after-reaching-its-end-using-c-rbix)